# What is the difference between Republish, Smart Publish and Incremental Publish?

Tags: publish, sitecore8

While publishing an item in Sitecore, there are three options
1.Republish
2 Smart Publish
3 Incremental Publish
What are these, and what makes them different?

Comment: Did you even use a search engine before asking? https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/384/what-is-the-difference-between-republish-smart-publish-and-incremental-publishe

Answer (score 0):

Publishing is the process of moving an item from master DB to Web DB. We can have multiple publishing DB's and we can choose this at the time of publishing.

The publishing types are as follows:

**Republish** - This will publish the entire items .

**Smart publish** - This will check all the items and publish if there is a change in an item.

**Incremental Publish** - Everytime if you made any change in an item it will add in the publishing queue. Those queued items are published in this option.